# C++ boost.asio server and client connection undersanding

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

i started learning boost.asio and i have some problems with undersanding tcp connections. There is example from official boost site:

```
  #include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string make_daytime_string()
{
  using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
  time_t now = time(0);
  return ctime(&now);
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13));

    for (;;)
    {
      tcp::socket socket(io_service);
      acceptor.accept(socket);

      std::string message = make_daytime_string();

      boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
      boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message),
          boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);
    }
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

there is question, why if i want to connet to this server via client i have t write:

```
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
tcp::resolver::query query(host_ip, "daytime"); //why daytime?
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
tcp::resolver::iterator end;
```

why daytime?, what it meant and where it is inicialized in server, or i just doesn't missed somefing?

there is full client code : www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1.html
thanks for explanation in advance

Answer (score 6):

Daytime is simply another protocol (like FTP, etc) and it uses port 13. If you want to connect to the server on a specific port number, then your code would look like this:

```
tcp::resolver::query query(host_ip, "5678"); // 5678 is the port number
```

Comment: thnx for ansewer, but can i use no a "daytime" word, but only number of port in my client

Comment: @EdgarBuchvalov In my answer, I showed you how you can use a specific port number. `tcp::resolver::query query(host_ip, "13");` would be the same as using `"daytime"`.

Answer (score 1):

daytime is the service name, this is well described in the `tcp::resolver::query` [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver_query/basic_resolver_query/overload3.html)

> **service_name**
>
> A string identifying the requested service. This may be a descriptive
>   name or a numeric string corresponding to a port number. May be an
>   empty string, in which case all resolved endpoints will have a port
>   number of 0.

Answer (score 0):

`"daytime"` means the port used for daytime services. It's the `13` you see at the acceptor. Here is a list of *well-known* ports (whatever that means):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: ok thnx,moreover is it possible to create my own port for connection to the server?
or creating own server i can use every port, from list you gave?

Comment: @Edgar Buchvalov: I'm not sure what you mean there... You can choose any port you want to do the connection.

Comment: no, for example now i write in fallowing way:
tcp::resolver::query query(host_ip, "daytime");
can i write:
tcp::resolver::query query(host_ip, 13); 
would it be the same

Comment: @Edgar Buchvalov: You should check ASIO reference, but I believe it would have to be `query(host_ip, "13")` instead.